# How do I output the hypothesis space symbol?

Tags: symbols

This [code](https://www.overleaf.com/read/xxqyfxhkxvjh)

```
$\mathcal{H}$
```

gives this symbol

[image]

while page 3 of https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring16/cos495/slides/ML_basics_lecture2_linear_classification.pdf

uses this symbol

[image]

How do I output the symbol pointed out by the arrow?

Which symbol should I use to denote the hypothesis space?

Comment: These slides seem to be made with Powerpoint and its equation editor that has a different font than the standard LaTeX one.

Comment: it's the same thing, just a different font the other characters probably have similar differences

Comment: This is a different font’s `\mathcal{H}`.  You can get a list of font specimens from [`unicode-math`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) and [`mathalpha`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf).